# Smoothly shut down ActiveMQ after running it for maven integration tests

Tags: java, maven, jms, cucumber, activemq-classic

I am running up ActiveMQ through Maven using "tcp://localhost:61616?useJmx=false&persistent=false". ActiveMQ runs up correctly with the Maven build and it is triggered succesfully for my integration tests. All the tests pass and the maven build is successful. However, when the activeMQ shuts down, it shows errors as under :-

```
Exception in thread "ActiveMQ ShutdownHook" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/activemq/transport/vm/VMTransportFactory
at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.stop(BrokerService.java:750)
at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerService.stop(XBeanBrokerService.java:91)
at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.containerShutdown(BrokerService.java:2303)
at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService$6.run(BrokerService.java:2270)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.activemq.transport.vm.VMTransportFactory
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:259)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:235)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:227)
... 4 more
```

How do I make the ActiveMQ shut down smoothly without the above error?